# Getting the datetime index within a Numpy Array Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, datetime, indexing

how can I write a code that shows me  the index of where the `Newdate1 and Newdate2` is located within `Setups`. The value for `Newdate1` within `Setups` is the second index which outputs `1` for `result`. The `np.where` function does not work however. How could I do this without a for loop?

```
import numpy as np 

Setups = np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000', '2017-09-15T11:25:00.000000000',
                   '2017-09-15T12:11:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:14:00.000000000',
                   '2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:31:00.000000000',
                   '2017-12-22T03:56:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")
    
Newdate1 =  np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000'], dtype="datetime64[ns]")
Newdate2 =  np.array(['2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000'], dtype="datetime64[ns]")

result = np.where(Setups == Newdate1)
result2 = np.where(Setups == Newdate2)
```

Expected Output:

```
result: 1
result2: 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `np.in1d` to pass the array to be searched within another array and get the indices using `np.where`.

```
import numpy as np 

Setups = np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000', '2017-09-15T11:25:00.000000000',
                   '2017-09-15T12:11:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:14:00.000000000',
                   '2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:31:00.000000000',
                   '2017-12-22T03:56:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")
    

newdates = np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000','2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")
print(np.where(np.in1d(Setups,newdates)))
```

output:

```
(array([0, 4]),)
```

Comment: hello there I have another question that is very similar to this i would appreciate it if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554897/getting-the-index-of-datetime-function-within-numpy-python