# Getting the index of datetime function within Numpy Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, datetime, indexing

The code down below finds the index of `newdates` within `Setups` with the `init_location` function. Then I increment the index by one to get the next date. But I cannot add to the `init_location` function. How would I be able to do that and get the expected value?

```
import numpy as np 

Setups = np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000', '2017-09-15T11:25:00.000000000',
                   '2017-09-15T12:11:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:14:00.000000000',
                   '2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000', '2017-12-22T03:31:00.000000000',
                   '2017-12-22T03:56:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")
    

newdates = np.array(['2017-09-15T07:11:00.000000000','2017-12-22T03:26:00.000000000'],dtype="datetime64[ns]")
init_location= np.where(np.in1d(Setups,newdates[1]))
print("init location: ", Setups[init_location],"Address right after: ",Setups[init_location+1])
```

Output Error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Expected Output

```
init location: 2017-12-22T03:26:00. Address right after: 2017-12-22T03:31:00.00
```

Comment: you'll want [np.nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html); something like `init_location = np.nonzero(np.in1d(Setups, newdates[1]))[0][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

becuase `init_location` is a tuple, you cannot add "1" directly . Instead use the following format.

```
print("init location: ", Setups[init_location],"Address right after: ",Setups[init_location[0]+1])
```

Comment: Thank you it works but it prints like this `['2018-11-14T16:21:00.000000000'] - ['2018-12-09T08:43:00.000000000']`  is there anychance I could make it print like `'2018-11-14 16:21:00 - 2018-12-09 08:43:00`

Comment: you can change the code to as follows `init_location= np.where(np.in1d(Setups,newdates[1]))[0][0]
print("init location: ", Setups[init_location],"Address right after: ",Setups[init_location+1])`